# MySQL - How can I improve these queries?

Tags: mysql

first one:

```
SELECT MONTH(timestamp) AS d, COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM table
WHERE YEAR(timestamp)=2012 AND Status = 1
GROUP BY MONTH(timestamp)
```

one of the issues I'm facing for this one is that I have to run multiple queries that use different values for `Status`. Is there a way to combine them into one? Like in one column it would have all the counts for when `Status=1` and another column for when `Status=2`, etc.

second one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c , MONTH(timestamp) t FROM
(
SELECT t.adminid, timestamp
FROM  table1 t 
LEFT JOIN admins a ON a.adminID=t.adminID
WHERE YEAR(timestamp)=2012          
GROUP BY t.adminID, DATE(Timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) AS a
GROUP BY MONTH(timestamp)
ORDER BY MONTH(timestamp) ASC;
```

a nested query, not sure if I can improve on this. I'm running this one on 2 tables, one has ~35k rows and one has ~300k rows. It takes about half a second for the first table and 4-5 seconds for the second.

Comment: How many status columns do you need?

Comment: for the first one? 4 columns, 1 for date, and 3 for 3 different ``status`` Second query only 2, one for count and one for month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might help:

First one:

```
SELECT MONTH(timestamp) AS d, 
sum(case when Status=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Status1Count,
sum(case when Status=2 then 1 else 0 end) as Status2Count,
sum(case when Status=3 then 1 else 0 end) as Status3Count
FROM `table`
WHERE timestamp between '2012-01-01 00:00:00' and '2012-12-31 23:59:59' 
AND Status in (1,2,3)
GROUP BY MONTH(timestamp);
```

Second one:

Make sure that there is an index on the `timestamp` column and then make sure that you do not run any conversion functions e.g. `MONTH(timestamp)` on the indexed column. Somthing like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c , a.m as t FROM
(
SELECT t.adminid, timestamp, MONTH(timestamp) as m
FROM  table1 t 
LEFT JOIN admins a ON a.adminID=t.adminID
WHERE timestamp between '2012-01-01 00:00:00' and '2012-12-31 23:59:59'          
GROUP BY t.adminID, DATE(Timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) AS a
GROUP BY a.m
ORDER BY a.m ASC;
```

Second one is a bit tricky since I do not have the data in front of me so I can't see the DB access path!

Comment: the first query worked great but unfortunately it didnt reduce the runtime at all, I was mistaken. and thanks for the tip on indexing, I will give that a shot.